# Problem finding number of elements in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, date, sum

I have downloaded the data frame `casos_hosp_uci_def_sexo_edad_provres_60_mas.csv`, which describes the amount of people infected from Covid-19 in Spain classified for their province, age, gender... from [this webpage](https://cnecovid.isciii.es/covid19/#documentaci%C3%B3n-y-datos). I read and represent the dataframe as:

```
db<-read.csv(file = 'casos_hosp_uci_def_sexo_edad_provres.csv')
```

The first five rows are shown

```
      provincia_iso sexo grupo_edad      fecha num_casos num_hosp num_uci num_def

1               A    H        0-9 2020-01-01         0        0       0       0
2               A    H      10-19 2020-01-01         0        0       0       0
3               A    H      20-29 2020-01-01         0        0       0       0
4               A    H      30-39 2020-01-01         0        0       0       0
5               A    H      40-49 2020-01-01         0        0       0       0
```

The first four colums of the data frame show the name of the province, gender of the people, age group and date, the latest four columns show the number of people who got ill, were hospitalized, in ICU or dead.

I want to use R to find the day with the highest rate of contagions. To do that, I have to sum the elements of the fifth row `num_casos` for each different value of the column `fecha`.

I have already been able to calculate the number of sick males as `hombresEnfermos=sum(db[which(db$sexo=="H"), 5])`. However, I think there has to be a better way to check the days with higher contagion than go manually counting. However, I cannot find out how.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` to get the total by date:

```
library(dplyr)  

db %>% group_by(fecha) %>% summarise(total = sum(num_casos))
```

Two alternatives in base R:

```
data.frame(fecha = sort(unique(db$fecha)), 
       total = sapply(split(db, f = db$fecha), function(x) {sum(x[['num_casos']])}))
```

Or more simply,

```
aggregate(db$num_casos, list(db$fecha), FUN=sum)
```

An alternative in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

db <- as.data.table(db)
db[, list(total=sum(num_casos)), by = fecha]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used the base R. If it is not a problem, could you tell me how to chech just for `provincia_iso` having the value A?

Comment: Sure thing. If you would like to get the totals just for `provincia_iso` having a value of A, you can first subset the data and then use the same procedure outlined above; create `db_sub <- db[db$provincia_iso == "A", ]` and replace `db` in the code above with `db_sub`.